# How to select a field from a dataframe if a particular condition is achieved?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a scenario where I have some data in a csv file and I retrieved it and store in a dataframe. Now I need to iterate through each row based on a particular condition. If that condition is met then I need to retrieve one field of that row.

For Example:
I have data related to cricket players in a dataframe. Now I want to select the name of the player with the highest batting average.

Can anyone please help me out with this issue?

```
print("The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be: ",
      dataset['Names'].loc[(dataset['Average'] == max(dataset['Average'])) & (dataset['Innings'] >= 15)])
```

The Expected Output must be the player with the highest aggregate such as Virat Kohli etc...

I am getting the output but there are some minor errors as well as follows:
The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be:  2    Virat Kohli
Name: Names, dtype: object

Here I don't want to print anything after the ':' except 'Virat kohli'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure there is a match,  you can use `idxmax()` after the condition in `Innings`:

```
print("The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be: ",
  df.loc[df.loc[df.Innings>=15,'Average'].idxmax(),'Names'])
```

---

**Output**

```
The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be:  Virat Kohli
```

Comment: When I try to use the same code above as follows:

`print("The Leading Wicket taker of the Tournament could well be: ", 
      dataset.loc[dataset.loc[dataset['Wickets']].idxmax(),'Names'])`

I am getting the following error:

TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Don't know why!

Comment: @Vivek if the dtype of `Wickets` column is object, it will throw error, it should be int if i understand correctly. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767084/typeerror-reduction-operation-argmax-not-allowed-for-this-dtype

Answer (score 1):

You're close but need to get your syntax right. Use:

```
print("The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be: ",
      dataset.loc[(dataset['Average'] == dataset['Average'].max()) & (dataset['Innings'] >= 15), ['Names']].iloc[0])
```

Instead of using  `max(dataset['Average'])`, use  `dataset['Average'].max(`), because it's faster. Also `loc` allows you to specify column you want and hence the `['Names']` and `iloc` to retrieve the first element

Answer (score 1):

There should be problem if no value is matched, then `idxmax` return first value wrongly, better is use `next` with `iter` here:

```
a =  dataset.loc[(dataset['Average'] == dataset['Average'].max()) & 
                 (dataset['Innings'] >= 15), 'Names']
print("The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be:
                               {}".format(next(iter(a), 'no match')))
```